# Multiple authors in one row with refmark, multiple affiliations in separated columns in another row

Tags: formatting, titles, authblk

I wonder how we can list author names in the following format in LaTeX.

I have 5 authors with 3 different affiliations. I am trying to list all author names with refmark in one row, and 3 affiliations with refmark in another row, but each in one separated column. It should look like this:

```
        author1{1} author2{2} author3{1} author4{2} author5{3}
           {1}department      {2}department        {3}department
              school              school              school
              email                email              email
```

I did saw some papers that have the above format, but cannot search for any guideline. IEEE guideline suggests another way to list authors, but sadly it does not look that neat

```
        author1{1} author2{2} author3{1} author4{2} author5{3}
                        {1} department, school
                              email
                        {2} department, school
                              email
                        {3} department, school
                              email
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: It may be possible to sort this via the [`titling`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titling) package.

Answer (score 7):

Since this seems to be a request for a one-time use, I would opt for a manual design of the title; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{url}

\newcommand\Mark[1]{\textsuperscript#1}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\centering
{\LARGE The Title \\[1.5em]
\large First Author\Mark{1}, Second Author\Mark{2}, Third Author\Mark{1}, Fourth Author\Mark{2} and Fifth Author\Mark{3}}\\[1em]
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{>{\centering}p{.25\textwidth}}}
\Mark{1}Department1 & \Mark{2}Department2 & \Mark{3}Department3 \tabularnewline
School1 & School2 & School3 \tabularnewline
\url{email1} & \url{email2} & \url{email3}
\end{tabular}\par
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Even if it may not look exactly like your specification I think it makes sense to mentioned the [`authblk`](http://ctan.org/pkg/authblk) package which makes it easy to handle multiple authors of which some shares affiliations. You may choose between two layouts (there are some options in addition to the layouts but they are not relevant here, check the manual learn about them).

### Footnote style

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}% For email addresses

\title{Title}

\author[1]{Lisa}
\author[2]{John}
\author[1]{Jessica}
\author[2]{Chris}
\author[3]{Anna}

\affil[1]{Department 1 \\
School 1 \\
\url{email1}}
\affil[2]{Department 2 \\
School 2 \\
\url{email2}}
\affil[3]{Department 3 \\
School 3 \\
\url{email3}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image: authblk with footnote style]

### Author block

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[blocks]{authblk}% The option is for block layout
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}% For email addresses

\title{Title}

\author{Lisa}
\author{Jessica}
\affil{Department 1 \\% If the blocks option of authblk is removed \\ is treated as ,
School 1 \\
\url{email1}}

\author{John}
\author{Chris}
\affil{Department 2 \\
School 2 \\
\url{email2}}

\author{Anna}
\affil{Department 3 \\
School 3 \\
\url{email3}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image: authblk with author block]

Answer (score 0):

Try this! I think it's what you wanted!

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\title{Article Title}

\author{
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{>{\centering}p{.5\textwidth}}}
\large Nome1 & \large Nome2 \tabularnewline
Department1 & Department2 \tabularnewline
School1 & School2 \tabularnewline
\url{url1} & \url{url2} 
\end{tabular}
}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Depending on the number of authors, you should always adjust the column's width, to .5\textwidh, .25\textwidth etc.

Result:

[image]