# authors with multiple affiliations without packages

Tags: titles, affiliation

I'm trying to list an author with multiple affiliations for an article submission. I Googled around a little and discovered the `authblk` package which is pretty cool. Unfortunately it refuses to work with the conference specified LaTeX files:

Is there any workaround solution to list multiple affiliations for a single author without any extra packages? The help would be appreciated.

Comment: What about [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29684/5764)  to [Multiple authors in one row with refmark, multiple affiliations in separated columns in another row](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29669/5764)?

Answer (score 1):

In the .sty provided, you can read the instruccions for working with the `\author` command. It's simply a tabular enviroment. So this might be a way of coping with several institutions, e.g.:

```
\author{Author 1\\
  XYZ Company\\
  111 Anywhere Street\\
  Mytown, NY 10000, USA\\
  {\tt author1@xyz.org}\\[3pt] % add vspace for next institution
  ABC Company\\ % next institution 
  234 Street\\
  Other City, XX 00000, CT\\
  {\tt author1@abc.org}\\
\And
Author 2\\
  ABC University\\
  900 Main Street\\
  Ourcity, PQ, Canada A1A 1T2\\
  {\tt author2@abc.ca}}
```

Comment: But this simply adds the 2nd affiliation below the first... I was looking for something more along the lines of what authblk produces (i.e. with footnotes and all three institutions in the same row)

Comment: @user13321: if you are using the style provided by the conference, it doesn't seem convenient to make big modifications to the layout.