# Latex : Three authors with two affiliations

Tags: formatting, titles, affiliation

I have three authors associated with a paper. All of them share the same university, but the second one also has an extra university address.

I would like something like the following :

[image: example image]

Comment: This question and both of its answers might be helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29669/multiple-authors-in-one-row-with-refmark-multiple-affiliations-in-separated-col

Comment: Also: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.