# how to put 4 authors in a single row in ACM conf format?

Tags: acm, author

I have four authors in the paper and they are by-default arranged as follows:

```
Author1            Author2
Author3            Author4
```

Is there a way to force the format to put authors in a single row as follows?

```
Author1            Author2         Author3            Author4
```

Code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{} 

\setlength{\textfloatsep}{5pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1.5pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{1.5pt}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
%\acmDOI{10.475/123_4}

% ISBN
%\acmISBN{123-4567-24-567/08/06}

%Conference
\acmConference[Conf'18]{International Conference on Something}{May 2018}{Earth} 
%\acmYear{2018}
\copyrightyear{2018}

%\acmPrice{15.00}

 \setcopyright{none} 

\settopmatter{printacmref=false} % Removes citation information below abstract
\makeatletter
\def\-copyrightspace{\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{Document Title}


\author{Author1}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Company 1}}

\author{Author2}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Company2}}

\author{Author3}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Company2}}

 \author{Author4}    
 \affiliation{%
  \institution{Company2}}
```

I want to know if there is way to put all four authors in a single row. Currently these are coming in 2 rows with 2 authors in one row as shown above.

Comment: What is the documentclass, could you post a MWE?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Related:[Multiple authors in one row with refmark ...](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29684/124842)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The class `acmart` allows to set the number of authors per row by inserting e.g.

```
\settopmatter{authorsperrow=4}
```

after `\documentclass{acmart}`.

In your example this results in
[image]